# how to edit multiple menu itmes on menu management page

Tags: routes, nodes

Is there a way to edit multiple menu items on menu management page. I have a site with lots of menu items under one menu, if I want to change the parent of multiple menu items I will need to drag each menu item individually to the parent. Is there a way we can select multiple menu items and change there parent.

And is there a module which allows us to collapse and expand the menus as per our requirement.

Some thing like Taxonomy Manager Module.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think there is a module that lets you do bulk menu item edits. another option you might want to try is just show the weights of each item and manaually adjust it in that manner so you dont have to drag each one.[image]